# jsp calls 2 servlets through jquery

Tags: jsp, jquery, servlets

**Background:**
i have - Search.jsp, SearchResult.java and SearchDetails.java files. i need to post the search values to the SearchResult servlet via jquery/(ajax?) on form submit and display the result in a 1-column table.
after that user can click on any row to view that result's details in the same page. in this case my plan is to on click event of the specific row i have to call SearchDetails servlet via jquery-ajax.

**Problem:**
i can now get the search result within a dynamically populated table and within each row i am populating the result within a /link tag.
1. pls tell me how the result can be populated in a table so that i can do the pagination, etc.
2. how can i call the SearchDetails servlet with a hidden value stored in a dynamically populated td.

**My Experience:** i am working on jsp, servlet, jquery-ajax from last 1 month. but did .net last 7 yrs.

Search.jsp:

```
<script> 
 $(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#btnSearch').click(function() { 
        $mobileNo = document.getElementById("txtMobileNo").value;
        $.post('BE_AccountSearch', {mobileNo:$mobileNo}, 
        function(responseText){ 
              $('#dvSearchResultSub').html(responseText); 
         }); 
     }); 
 }); 
</script> 
<form id="form" method="post"> 
     <input name="txtMobileNo" id="txtMobileNo" autofocus> 
     <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search"/> 
     <div id="dvSearchResultSub"></div> 
</form>
```

SearchResult.java (servlet):

```
out.println("<table>"); 
for (int i = 0; i < memberList.size(); i++){ 
  out.println("<tr>"); out.println("<td>"); 
  out.println("<a id=\"memberList\" href=\"BE_AccountDetails?uln=" + memberList.get(i).getUsername() + "\">"); 
  out.println(memberList.get(i).getUsername());
  out.println("</a>"); 
  out.println("</td>"); 
 out.println("</tr>"); 
} 
out.println("</table>"); 
out.println("</div>"); 
out.flush(); 
out.close();
```

Comment: **Search.jsp:**
`<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#btnSearch').click(function() {
       $mobileNo = document.getElementById("txtMobileNo").value;
                        $.post('BE_AccountSearch', {mobileNo:$mobileNo}, function(responseText){
         $('#dvSearchResultSub').html(responseText);
   });
  });
});
</script>`
`<form id="form" method="post">
 <input name="txtMobileNo" id="txtMobileNo" autofocus>
 <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search"/>
 <div id="dvSearchResultSub"></div>
</form>`

Comment: **SearchResult.java (servlet):**
`out.println("<table>");
 for (int i = 0; i < memberList.size(); i++){
   out.println("<tr>");
   out.println("<td>");
   out.println("<a id=\"memberList\" href=\"BE_AccountDetails?uln=" + memberList.get(i).getUsername() + "\">");                    out.println(memberList.get(i).getUsername());
   out.println("</a>");
   out.println("</td>");
   out.println("</tr>");
}
out.println("</table>");
out.println("</div>");
out.flush();
out.close();
`

Comment: so, the above code is running nicely. but when i clicked the resulted values it directly open the 'BE_AccountDetails' page as i used the link button.
what i want to do is - by clicking the link i want to execute the 2nd servlet with the mobile no and get around 30/35 fields' data (fName, mName, lName, etc.) and show it on this page.

Comment: You can edit the question. Use comments only for short clarification,suggestion etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java MVC (Model View Controller) to pass the parameters from jsp to Java and back to Jsp. You can get some help [here](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/javamvcdesignpattern.html).

For populating a table on jsp using AJAX, you can use [Datatables](http://datatables.net/). Datatables provide a lot of functionality on the tables like pagination, searching, sorting, etc.

I hope this helps. Provide some code along with your question if you have started with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I use for such tasks jqGrid. It has embedded ajax. All you have to do is insert it into your page and create servlet/controller that process queries.

From your code all looks fine. Don't know where problem is. Try to run it in FireFox with FireBug on and look at trace - there should be an errors if it does not show the dynamic result.